# ASP.NET MVC application not working after publish in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on an asp.net mvc application, its fully functional in my development pc but after deployment in production(iis 7.5, WS 2008 R2) it's not working. When I give the login credential and submit the ajax post request return 200 ok with the same login page, it's not hit the controller post method.

1. Web.config : -

   ```
   <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">      
      <forms name="IMTCMS" loginUrl="~/Account/RedirectToLogin" protection="All" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
2. login.cshtml : -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Login Page - Ace Admin</title>

    <meta name="description" content="User login page" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- text fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/fonts/fonts.googleapis.com.css" />

    <!-- ace styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/ace.min.css" />

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/ace-part2.min.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/ace-rtl.min.css" />

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/ace-ie.min.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="~/Content/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="login-layout light-login" style="background: url(../Content/img/Globalfootprint.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;background-size:cover;">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="login-container ">
                        <div class="center">
                            
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="space-6"></div>

                        <div class="position-relative">
                            <div id="login-box" class="login-box visible widget-box no-border">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="widget-main">
                                        <h1 class="center">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-leaf green"></i>
                                            <span class="red">IMT</span>
                                            <span class="grey" id="id-text2">SMS</span>
                                        </h1>
                                        <h4 class="blue" id="id-company-text">&copy; Beximco Pharmaceuticals Ltd.</h4>
                                        <h4 class="header blue lighter bigger">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-coffee green"></i>
                                            Please Enter Your Information
                                        </h4>

                                        <div class="space-6"></div>

                                        <form>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <div class="space"></div>

                                                <div class="clearfix">
                                                    <label class="inline">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                                                        <span class="lbl"> Remember Me</span>
                                                    </label>

                                                    <a type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="UserLogin();">
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
                                                        <span class="bigger-110">Login</span>
                                                        @*<a class="btn btn-default submit" href="@Url.Action("ModeList", "Home")">Log in</a>*@
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="space-4"></div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div><!-- /.widget-main -->

                                    <div class="toolbar clearfix">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" data-target="#forgot-box" class="forgot-password-link">
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                                I forgot my password
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" data-target="#signup-box" class="user-signup-link">
                                                I want to register
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
                            </div><!-- /.login-box -->

                            <div id="forgot-box" class="forgot-box widget-box no-border">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="widget-main">
                                        <h4 class="header red lighter bigger">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
                                            Retrieve Password
                                        </h4>

                                        <div class="space-6"></div>
                                        <p>
                                            Enter your email and to receive instructions
                                        </p>

                                        <form>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <div class="clearfix">
                                                    <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                                                        <span class="bigger-110">Send Me!</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div><!-- /.widget-main -->

                                    <div class="toolbar center">
                                        <a href="#" data-target="#login-box" class="back-to-login-link">
                                            Back to login
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
                            </div><!-- /.forgot-box -->

                            <div id="signup-box" class="signup-box widget-box no-border">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="widget-main">
                                        <h4 class="header green lighter bigger">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users blue"></i>
                                            New User Registration
                                        </h4>

                                        <div class="space-6"></div>
                                        <p> Enter your details to begin: </p>

                                        <form>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" />
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-retweet"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <label class="block">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                                                    <span class="lbl">
                                                        I accept the
                                                        <a href="#">User Agreement</a>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>

                                                <div class="space-24"></div>

                                                <div class="clearfix">
                                                    <button type="reset" class="width-30 pull-left btn btn-sm">
                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh"></i>
                                                        <span class="bigger-110">Reset</span>
                                                    </button>

                                                    <button type="button" class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
                                                        <span class="bigger-110">Register</span>

                                                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="toolbar center">
                                        <a href="#" data-target="#login-box" class="back-to-login-link">
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                            Back to login
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
                            </div><!-- /.signup-box -->
                        </div><!-- /.position-relative -->
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.main-content -->
    </div><!-- /.main-container -->
    <!-- basic scripts -->
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='~/Content/js/jquery.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
    </script>

    <!-- <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='~/Content/js/jquery1x.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) document.write("<script src='~/Content/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
    </script>

    <!-- inline scripts related to this page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document).on('click', '.toolbar a[data-target]', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = $(this).data('target');
                $('.widget-box.visible').removeClass('visible');//hide others
                $(target).addClass('visible');//show target
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //fill the vehicale type
        //getVehicleType();
    });   

    function UserLogin() {
        // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object

        // Creating info Json Object
        var info = { "EmpID": "", "Password": "" };

        // Set info Json Object Value

        info.EmpID = $("#username").val();
        info.Password = $("#password").val();
        //info.Condition = "1";

        // Step 1: Ends Here


        // Set 2: Ajax Post
        // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/Login',
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == "1") {                   
                    window.location.href = result.url;
                    alert("User saved successfully, please check mail to confirm registration and then login");
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.Success == "2") {
                    alert(result.ex);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    alert(result.ex);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }

    //*********Start : InformationSave() Function
    //This function is used for sending data(JSON Data) to Account Controller
    function NewRegistration() {
        // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object

        // Creating info Json Object
        var info = { "Email": "", "EmpID": "", "Password": "", "PhoneNo": "", "DeptUID": "", "Condition": "" };

        // Set info Json Object Value

        info.Email = $("#email-address").val();
        info.EmpID = $("#emp-code").val();
        info.Password = $("#password").val();
        info.PhoneNo = $("#phone-no").val();
        info.DeptUID = $("#department").val();
        info.Condition = "1";
        //info.UID = "1";
        //info.InfoID = "1";

        // Step 1: Ends Here


        // Set 2: Ajax Post
        // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/ProfileEntry',
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == "1") {
                    alert("User saved successfully, please check mail to confirm registration and then login");
                    //window.location.href = "#";
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.Success == "2") {
                    var error = '';
                    //if Problem happend during the validation, display
                    // the messages. The following script will display the last
                    // message related to the field.
                    //$.each(result.ex, function (key, value) {
                    //    if (value != null) {
                    //        error += value[value.length - 1].ErrorMessage + '\n';
                    //    }
                    //});

                    //alert(error);
                    alert(result.ex);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    alert(result.ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //*********End : InformationSave() Function

    //*********Start : PasswordSave() Function
    //This function is used for sending data(JSON Data) to Account Controller
    function ForgotPassword() {
        // Step 1: Read View Data and Create JSON Object

        // Creating info Json data
        var email = $("#email-add").val();
        //alert(email);
        // Step 1: Ends Here


        // Set 2: Ajax Post
        // Here i have used ajax post for saving/updating information

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/ForgotPassword',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { "email": email },
            //contentType: 'application/json;',
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == "1") {
                    alert(result.ex);
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.Success == "2") {
                    alert(result.ex);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    alert(result.ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //*********End : PasswordSave() Function
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

3. Account Controller:-

   ```
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {

     private LoginManager loginManager = null;
     LoginUser loginUser = null;  

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {

        try
        {
            loginUser = HttpContext.Session["UserProfile"] as LoginUser;
            new LoginManager().LoginManagement(new User { UID = loginUser.SlNo, Condition = "2" });

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
        }
        catch
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();                 
        }                         

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }

    // URL to redirect user to login page when session timeout
    // GET: /Account/RedirectToLogin
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
    {
        return PartialView("_RedirectToLogin");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(User info)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //get user browser information
                info.BrowserInfo = "( Browser : " + HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser +
                                   " )  (Version : " +  HttpContext.Request.Browser.Version +
                                   " )  ( Type : " + HttpContext.Request.Browser.Type + 
                                   " )  ( Platform : " + HttpContext.Request.Browser.Platform + 
                                   " )  ( UserAgent : " + HttpContext.Request.UserAgent +
                                   " )  ( UserLang : " + HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0].ToString() + " ) " ;



                loginManager = new LoginManager();
                LoginUser loginuser = loginManager.GetUserInfo(info);

                if (loginuser != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(info.EmpID, false);
                    HttpContext.Session["UserProfile"] = loginuser;

                    //start : new change 31/05/2017
                    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, info.EmpID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, "Admin");
                    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
                    //end : new change 31/05/2017

                    return Json(new { Success = 1, url = Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard") });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = 2, ex = "Please fill all (*) required fields" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If Sucess== 0 then Unable to perform Save/Update Operation and send Exception to View as JSON
            return Json(new { Success = 0, ex = ex.Message.ToString() });
        }
        finally
        {
            //accountManager = null;
            info = null;
        }
        return View();
    }        



   }
   ```

Comment: That's quite a large list of end of life technologies all in one production deployment.

Comment: Go to "Control Pannel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off"  and  compare the IIS components installed in these two servers, maybe something is missing

Comment: The server is not finding the data.  Check connection string to see source of data.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, my problem is solved. Jdweng you are right problem was with the connection string. I just made the "integrated security" option "false" in connection string and it's working fine.